# problems placing submit button in a responsive web page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a web page that displays one dropdown box when the page loads, and a submit button beside it.  Depending on what option the user selects from the dropdown, I make ajax calls and if data is returned, I display another drop down list with more options.  I do this 2 times, so that in total, you can have up to 3 drop downs on the page side by side.  all the while, the submit button is supposed to be to the right of the last drop down box that's displayed.

**Problem:**

Depending on which mobile device I'm using to navigate the site, the submit button overlaps with the first drop down box even if there's plenty of room on the row. The same thing happnes when the second drop down appears.  How can I ensure that regardless of the device, the submit button always initially appears beside the first drop down?

**Code:**

I'm only showing the HTML... but the ajax all works.  The ajax code just adds select boxes within each div tag.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12" id="l1locations">
            <h2><?php echo $title;?></h2>

            <div class="span3">
                    <h4>Branch:</h4>
                    <select name='L1Locations' id='L1Locations'>
                        <option selected value''></option>
                        <?php
                            foreach ($branches as $key=>$value)
                            {
                                echo '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$value."</option>";
                            }

                        ?>
                    </select>   
            </div>
            <div class="span3" id="l2locations"></div>
            <div class="span4" id="l3locations"></div>
            <h4>&nbsp;</h4>
            <button class="btn search">Search</button>
        </div>
</div>
```

**What I've tried so far:**

I've increased the spans from span3 to span4 for the first two drop downs and that works.  but when the page initially displays, the button is super far away from the first drop down.
Is there a simpler way to do this that I'm missing?

Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

Here's some code showing the rendered HTML... with the first drop down populated, and the submit button overlapping it:

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="locationsbar">         
    <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12" id="l1locations">
                <h2>Show Location:</h2>

                <div class="span3">
                        <h4>Branch:</h4>
                        <select name='L1Locations' id='L1Locations'>
                            <option selected value''></option>
                            <option value="185">Loc1</option><option value="63">Loc2</option><option value="198">Loc3</option><option value="197">Loc4</option><option value="196">Loc5</option><option value="110">Loc6</option><option value="8">Loc7</option></select>   
                </div>
                <div class="span3" id="l2locations"></div>
                <div class="span4" id="l3locations"></div>
                <h4>&nbsp;</h4>
                <button class="btn search">Search</button>
            </div>
    </div>
    <!-- DISPLAY RESULTS -->
    <div class="row-fluid">

                <div class="span12 visible-desktop visible-tablet" id="l1locations">
                        <table id="switchrecords" name="switchrecords" class="table table-bordered">

                        </table>
                </div>

                <div class="span12 visible-phone" id="l1locations">
                        <div id="mobileswitchrecords">

                        </div>
                </div>              

    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT 2**

Here's the html that's generated to populate the second drop down via ajax:

Sub Loc 1:AllB1B2B124B97B89

Had to do an alert statement / console.log because ajax doesn't update the actual code on page ...

Comment: Can you show the generated HTML, after all 3 select boxes have been added?

Comment: Your CSS will be needed to solve this issue.

Comment: Diodeus, I'm just using the default bootstrap-responsive.css.

Comment: Chris Rockwell, check out my Edit 1

Comment: Diodeus, if you tell me specifically which element you want, I will use the INSPECT tool in FF to get you the css that's being applied. Would that help?

Comment: koala_dev, it's ajax.  So you won't see the markup for the 2nd or 3rd drop downs.  But i will do a console.log on the htmlstring I'm using to build the select via jquery.  Check out edit 2.  Also, the button should always be to the right of the last drop down that's displayed.  I only mention drop down 1 because as soon as the page is displayed on certain devices, the submit button has already overlapped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your markup would look something like this

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span3" id="L1Locations">
        <h4>Branch:</h4>
        <select name='L1Locations'>
            <option selected value=''></option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="span3" id="L2Locations">
        <h4>Branch:</h4>
        <select name='L2Locations'>
            <option selected value=''></option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="span3" id="L2Locations">
        <h4>Branch:</h4>
        <select name='L2Locations'>
            <option selected value=''></option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <button class="btn search">Search</button>
</div>
```

Try adding this to your CSS

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    #L1Locations, #L2Locations, #L3Locations {
        float: none;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0;
        width: auto;
        text-align: left;
    }
    .row-fluid {
        text-align: center;
    }
    select {
        margin: 0;
    }
}
```

This will make all columns take only the width of their content and appear side by side on large screens (>= 768px) by using `display:inline-block;` instead of floats. Behavior in small devices remains unaffected, Bootstrap makes all columns in small devices act like block elements (taking the full with of their container)

**[Demo with 3 selects](http://jsfiddle.net/9cYCA/9/)**

**[Demo with 1 select](http://jsfiddle.net/9cYCA/9/)**

**UPDATE**

In response to your comment, you could get a similar effect using the default Bootstrap grid system, but you would need to do two things:

1. Fix your markup, when you want to nest rows, you need to include another `<div class="row-fluid">` inside your column, also every direct descendant of your `.row-fluid` should be an elements with class `.spanX`, that means you can't have your `<button>` as sibling of your spans
2. Since `.spanX` elements will take up their specified width even when they're empty, the button will always be away from the first select unless you dynamically append your second and third `.span3` columns with your ajax callback

So you'd have this as your initial markup

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
        <h2>My title</h2>
        <div class="row-fluid"> <!--You need to define a nested row-->
            <div class="span3" id="L1Locations">
                <h4>Branch:</h4>
                <select name='L1Locations'>
                    <option selected value=''></option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="span3">
                <h4>&nbsp;</h4>
                <button class="btn search">Search</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and would dynamically append the other selects wrapped in their columns

**[See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9cYCA/26/embedded/result/)**

Comment: That's perfect!  I had to make a small adjustment because I didn't want the row data to be centered.  But can you just explain what this is doing exactly?  And why i couldn't do this with the grid system in bootstrap?  sorry, i'm still so new to css.